# Service Worker Cached PDF Responses Missing Data

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, response, service-worker

When I use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to display a PDF in the browser, there's no way (that I have found) to include a file name. Therefore, when the user then goes to download what they see and like, the blob gibberish is all they get.

[image: See? Gibberish.]

Using a service worker and cached responses, however, I'm able to persist the file names to the new tabs.

```
// docServiceWorker.js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
        const store = await caches.open(DOCUMENTS_SW_CACHE_NAME);
        const req = event.request;
        const cached = await store.match(req);
        return cached || fetch(req);
    })());
});


---

// register
navigator.serviceWorker.register('docServiceWorker.js')
    .then(reg => { if (reg.installing) location.reload(); })
    .catch(console.error);

// clear previously cached files
(async () => {
    const store = await caches.open(DOCUMENTS_SW_CACHE_NAME);
    const keys = await store.keys();
    for (const req of keys) {
        store.delete(req);
    }
})();


---

//To open the file
async displayNamedDocument(file, filename) {
        const url = `${DOCUMENTS_SW_CACHE_NAME}${filename}`;
        const cache = await caches.open(DOCUMENTS_SW_CACHE_NAME);
        await cache.put(url, new Response(file));
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
```

[image: Now we're getting somewhere]

Unfortunately, other pertinent file information appears to be missing. If I attempt to download the file it displays as not found. If I try to dig into the file properties the button is disabled. It seems that the file is *there* but not really **there**.

With `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, the file data is intact. The browser knows it's a PDF and it can be downloaded, no problem.

[image: Obv PDF is obv]

[image: Works!]

I can select doc properties and view them:

[image: See? Props]

[image: There they are]

With the cached responses, we're missing all of that.
Here's the cached response that's returned via the service worker:

[image: Not much here]

And what you see when it loads in a new tab and you interact with the document:

Document properties unclickable (can't even hover on it):

[image: Can't click doc props]

And when you try to download, the browser doesn't know what it is:

[image: On download]

And once you've perhaps updated the name to PDF and completed the download, you really haven't - the file was never really there...

[image: Not really there?]

I should note that at one point I able to edit something (somewhere) with the response and change the contentDisposition from "*inline*" to "*attachment*" and the file automatically downloaded, all information intact.

Any ideas why I might be losing response data when it's cached in this fashion? Again, able to view the file and persist file name data, but can't download.